# When i type AF.request nothing shows up but Alamofire.request is working, but still .GET function is not shwoing up. How do i decode data

Tags: swift, alamofire

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        Alamofire.request("https://api.npoint.io/ad9bc4bdbf536cff1d3e").response { response in
            print(response.data)
        }
       
    }

}
```

Comment: Read doc : https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#response-json-handler

Comment: Which almofire version are you using. ```Alamofire.request``` is the old version and the new version is ```AF.request```

Comment: What's the Alamofire version you're using?

Comment: To decode data into a `Decodable` type, use `responseDecodable` and provide your type.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the old version of Alamofire, the new syntax is: `AF.request`

For a basic usage, handling the response is straightforward, just handle the 2 cases of your request response, one for success and one for the failure, with the error. For all the other cases, check the [documentation](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#using-alamofire).

```
AF.request("https://api.npoint.io/ad9bc4bdbf536cff1d3e").response { response in
        switch response.result {
              case .success(let data):
                    print("Handle success case")
              case let .failure(error):
                      print("Handle failure with \(error)")
        }
    }
```